# UITextView control line breaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView with items looking like this:

```
artist1 - song name1, artist2 - song name 2,
artist3 - song name3, etc.
```

I only want to disallow line breaks except between artists (after comma, before next artist), so this would be invalid:

```
artist 1 - song name1, artist 2 - // <- invalid break
song name 2.
```

I have tried two approaches for accomplishing this: Firstly, I put things in a webview, making this trivial to solve. Unfortunately, that is not possible for a couple of other reasons.

Secondly, I added _ where there are white spaces and hid them, like this:

```
artist_1_-_song_name1, artist_2_-_song_name_2, etc // <- setting colour of _ to invisible.
```

This almost worked, but now it breaks at the hyphen, like this:

```
artist_1_-
song_name1
```

I'm firstly looking for a good way to solve this. If that doesn't work, I would settle for a Unicode Char that looks like a dash but doesn't break (the U+2015 horizontal bar is too long)

Edit: Just found out about about Unicode Character 'NON-BREAKING HYPHEN' (U+2011), so while the problem is technically solved, I'm  still looking for a less hackish way to do it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a non breaking space, or Unicode Character u+00a0.

```
NSString *nonbreakingspace = @"\u00A0";
NSString *nonbreakinghyphen = @"\u2011";
```

An replace your spaces in the artist1 - song name1 with the nonbreakingspace string and the hyphen with the non breaking hyphen nonbreakinghyphen string.

```
NSString *text = ...;
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:nonbreakingspace];
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:nonbreakinghyphen];
myTextView.text = text;
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually figured it out myself shortly after finding the non breaking hyphen :).

Comment: FYI - You don't need to use a Unicode escape. Just enter the character directly. `NSString *nonbreakinghyphen = @"‑"; // non-breaking hyphen`

Answer (score 0):

swift 4 version!

```
var nonbreakinghyphen = "\u{2011}"
var text = "i-21"
myTextView.text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: nonbreakinghyphen)}
```